# Read Parquet file in Databricks using sparklyr

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks, sparklyr

Trying to read a Parquet file from R into Apache Spark 2.4.3 using the following code. It works on my local machine using Windows 10, but not on Databricks 5.5 LTS.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(arrow)

# Set up Spark connection
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(method = "databricks")

# Convert iris R data frame to Parquet and save to disk
arrow::write_parquet(iris, "/dbfs/user/iris.parquet")

# Read Parquet file into a Spark DataFrame: throws the error below
iris_sdf <- sparklyr::spark_read_parquet(sc, "iris_sdf", "user/iris.parquet")
```

> Error in record_batch_stream_reader(stream) : Error in
>   record_batch_stream_reader(stream) :    could not find function
>   "record_batch_stream_reader"

What could possibly be wrong here?

`SessionInfo()` on my local machine:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] arrow_0.16.0.2 sparklyr_1.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        rstudioapi_0.11   magrittr_1.5      bit_1.1-15.2      tidyselect_1.0.0  R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.5       httr_1.4.1        dplyr_0.8.5       tools_3.6.3       DBI_1.1.0         dbplyr_1.4.2      ellipsis_0.3.0    htmltools_0.4.0  
[15] bit64_0.9-7       assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_1.3-2   digest_0.6.25     tibble_2.1.3      forge_0.2.0       crayon_1.3.4      purrr_0.3.3       vctrs_0.2.4       base64enc_0.1-3   htmlwidgets_1.5.1 glue_1.3.1        compiler_3.6.3    pillar_1.4.3     
[29] generics_0.0.2    r2d3_0.2.3        backports_1.1.5   jsonlite_1.6.1    pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [Databricks Runtime 5.5 LTS](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/5.5.html) comes with sparklyr 1.0.0 ([released 2019-02-25](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sparklyr/)) but version 1.1.0 or above is needed. Install a newer version either through CRAN or GitHub, and `spark_read_parquet()` should work.

```
# CRAN
install.packages("sparklyr")

# GitHub
devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")

# You also need to install Apache Arrow
install.packages("arrow")
arrow_install()
```

Comment: You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.