Is there a way to read a parquet file from ADLS Gen2?
Is there a way to read a parquet/csv file from my Azure Blob storage (ADLS Gen2) from an Databricks R-notebook?
I have tried AzureStor, SparkR, but I all I get are errors. I just want to know if this is possible, at all? I want to read in the data and put it in an object that I can use/manipulate/read in my R notebook.
I tried packages AzureStor, SparkR, sparklyr.
This is my attempt with SparkR:
library(SparkR)

directory_id <- dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "asdf-ana-secrets", key = "dvh-adb-sto-tenantid")
service_credential <- dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "asdf-ana-secrets", key = "dvh-adb-sto-secret")
application_id <- dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "asdf-ana-secrets", key = "dvh-adb-sto-appid")
storage_account <- "myaccount"
container_name <- "mycontainer"

config <- list()

# Add Spark configurations for ADLS Gen2 access using OAuth
config["spark.hadoop.fs.azure"] = "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem"
config[paste0("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.", storage_account, ".dfs.core.windows.net")] = "OAuth"
config[paste0("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.", storage_account, ".dfs.core.windows.net")] = "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider"
config[paste0("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.", storage_account, ".dfs.core.windows.net")] = application_id
config[paste0("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.", storage_account, ".dfs.core.windows.net")] = service_credential
config[paste0("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.", storage_account, ".dfs.core.windows.net")] = paste0("https://login.microsoftonline.com/", directory_id, "/oauth2/token")

# Set up the Spark session with the configuration
sparkR.session(config = config)

# Define the path to the Parquet file in ADLS Gen2
file_path <- paste0("abfss://", container_name, "@", storage_account, ".dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/data.parquet")

# Read the Parquet file into a Spark DataFrame
df <- read.df(file_path, source = "parquet")

EDIT: my error message is:
Error : Error in load : Failure to initialize configuration for storage account myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:52)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:716)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.initializeClient(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:2149)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:276)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:251)
    at com.databricks.common.filesystem.LokiABFS.initialize(LokiABFS.scala:36)
    at com.databricks.common.filesystem.LokiFileSystem$.$anonfun$getLokiFS$1(LokiFileSystem.scala:163)
    at com.databricks.common.filesystem.FileSystemCache.getOrCompute(FileSystemCache.scala:43)
    at com.databricks.common.filesystem.LokiFileSystem$.getLokiFS(LokiFileSystem.scala:159)
    at com.databricks.common.filesystem.LokiFileSystem.initialize(LokiFileSystem.scala:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:350)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:41)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.diagnostics.ConfigurationBasicValidator.validate(ConfigurationBasicValidator.java:49)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.diagnostics.Base64StringConfigurationBasicValidator.validate(Base64StringConfigurationBasicValidator.java:40)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.validateStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:71)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:49)
    ... 56 more


Error: Error in load : Failure to initialize configuration for storage account myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

It works in python, so I'm trying to make the equivalent thing in R:
%python
directory_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="asdf-ana-secrets", key="dvh-adb-sto-tenantid")
service_credential = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="asdf-ana-secrets",key="dvh-adb-sto-secret")
application_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="asdf-ana-secrets", key="dvh-adb-sto-appid")
storage_account = "myaccount"
container_name = "mycontainer"

archive_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/this/works/file.csv"

spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", application_id)
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{directory_id}/oauth2/token")
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", ";").load(archive_path)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760443/read-parquet-file-in-databricks-using-sparklyr

@JohnPolo that does not make it clearer, sorry

As the error says:
Caused by: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
Set it:
spark.conf.set(f"fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net", "your account key")

or as described in OP
config[paste0("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.", storage_account, ".dfs.core.windows.net")] = "your account key"

See:

Error: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key to see if any of the other issues are applicable e.g. wrong storage account name.
https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/invalid-configuration-value-detected-for-fs-azure-account-key/td-p/30673


spark.conf.set is not available in R
